# Disable some code lines for Unit Test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode5, kif

I have issue with disabling some code lines for testing purpose.

I have 2 targets - 1st my Product, 2nd my KIF test target.
In KIF test target, macro is defined as KIF=1
In Product target, macro is defined as KIF=0

Then code was included in following:

```
#ifndef KIF
.... some code.....
#endif
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work for any target.

Maybe it happens because Product target is set in target dependency for KIF target?

Could you please help me to solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was more easy than i can imagine. Go to your Project > Configurations and create new configuration via tapping on plus '+' button > Duplicate Debug Configuration, then you can create new variable like TESTING and define it only for your configuration. The next step is include in #if your code and change configuration in your scheme.

```
#if TESTING
{
...some code for testing needs...
}
#else
{
...your regular code...
}
#endif
```

In Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Test, change Build Configuration to your own one and test it.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me for UnitTest as prebuild preprocessor macro.

```
#ifdef TEST
#endif
```

If you want a custom variables for custom builds do that:

1. Go to Target / Build Settings / Preprocessor Macros
2. Add desired variable: MYTESTVARIABLE
3. Now in code you can use that

.

```
#ifdef MYTESTVARIABLE 
//some code here
#endif
```

Comment: i've tried that but it doesn't work for me (i tried the both ways)